# Execute VBScript Function from C# with parameters

Tags: c#, com, vbscript

How do I call a function inside a VBScript file from C#? The function has 2 parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this.  The simplest would be to execute the VBScript file from a command line inside C#.  You would need to pass your parameters in at the command line, but the code would look similar to this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"cscript //B //Nologo c:\yourfile.vbs");
```

Here are more examples of how to execute command line functions in C#:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start

You can also get more advanced with these methods:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc301954.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974577.aspx

Comment: +1 for dotnetpearls.com ... great site with some good tutorials and a respectable source for info.